# How to filter the contents based on the selected objects from list using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 drop downs as Facility/Client and Master Plan code.

1. Now I select one client and one master Plan code. 
   So next time when I select the same Client and then the already selected master plan code shouldn't be shown in the dropdown list, but it must be hidden, and the same master plan code should be shown to other clients except for the selected one.
2. When I select All, in the Client drop down, in that which master plan code I select that shouldn't be shown in other clients, and if in case I had already selected any other Client with same master plan code, then that must be deleted. 
   So, here the purpose is, the same client code shouldn't contain the same master plan code.

Please help me in filtering the array of objects before adding to the list.

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4gkn5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Ts:

```
  addPlanCode() {
    let planCodeData = this.planCodeMappingFormBuilder.value;
    const jsonObj = {
    //  FieldValue: this.facilityId,
      IsPayerOffice: 1,
      planCodeExtensionID: 0,
      facilityCode: planCodeData.FacilityCode == "" ? null : planCodeData.FacilityCode,
      facilityName: planCodeData.FacilityCode == "*" ? "All" : this.facilities.filter(x=>x.facilityCode == planCodeData.FacilityCode)[0].facilityName,
      planCode: planCodeData.PlanCode,
      FieldType: "PO",
    };
    this.planCodeList.push(jsonObj);
  }


  public clear() {
    this.planCodeMappingFormBuilder = this.formbuilder.group({
      'FieldValue': [''],
      'FacilityCode': ['', Validators.required],
      'PlanCode': ['', Validators.required],
      'planCodeExtensionID': ['']
    })
  }


  deletePlanCode(planCodeList, index: any) {
    this.planCodeList.splice(index, 1);
    if (planCodeList.planCode) {
      this.deletedPlanCodeList.push(planCodeList);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose with this changes it will work as you need. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bc35ge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
1. For filtering list I append in component method, that filtering option in select element by Items in **planCodeList** with *facilityName == 'All'* and **facilityName** same as name in Form:

```
/** Returns the filtered Master Plan Code list for select element */
getFilteredPlans() {
  let formValue = this.planCodeMappingFormBuilder.value;
  let sameCodes = this.planCodeList.filter(x => x.facilityCode == formValue.FacilityCode);
  let allCodes = this.planCodeList.filter(x => x.facilityName == 'All');
  if (sameCodes.length > 0 || allCodes.length > 0) {
    let samePlanCodes = sameCodes.map(x => x.planCode);
    let sameAllCodes = allCodes.map(x => x.planCode);
    let filtered = this.planCode.filter(x => samePlanCodes.findIndex(y => y == x.planCode) < 0);
    filtered = filtered.filter(x => sameAllCodes.findIndex(y => y == x.planCode) < 0);
    return filtered; 
  }
  else 
    return this.planCode;
}
```

And in html template:

```
 <option *ngFor="let planCode of getFilteredPlans()" [value]="planCode.planCode">{{planCode.defaultPayerName}}{{" "}}({{planCode.planCode}})</option>
```

2. For deleting items when add Code with 'All' facilities I update method **addPlanCode**:

```
addPlanCode() {
    let planCodeData = this.planCodeMappingFormBuilder.value;
    const code = {
      //  FieldValue: this.facilityId,
        IsPayerOffice: 1,
        planCodeExtensionID: 0,
        facilityCode: planCodeData.FacilityCode == "" ? null : planCodeData.FacilityCode,
        facilityName: planCodeData.FacilityCode == "*" ? "All" : this.facilities.find(x=> x.facilityCode == planCodeData.FacilityCode).facilityName,
        planCode: planCodeData.PlanCode,
        FieldType: "PO",
    };
    if (planCodeData.FacilityCode == "*") {
      for (let i = this.planCodeList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this.planCodeList[i].planCode == planCodeData.PlanCode)
          this.planCodeList.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    this.planCodeList.push(code);
    this.planCodeMappingFormBuilder.reset();
  }
```

Comment: hi, thanks fr response, but i am not finding dropdown options to  test

Comment: Sorry, my changes doesn't saved in StackBlitz i will update it in few minutes

Comment: can u pls help me out

Comment: hi, thanks for update, here on click of edit button, i am able to see the client name but not the master plan code

Comment: can u pls help me out in that?

Comment: on click of edit, it is giving the new list instead of replacing the master plan code of that

Comment: In **getFilteredPlans()** in codeblock `if (this.editedIndex)  filtered.push(this.planCodeList[this.editedIndex]) }` create objct for your model, as you need, and push it to **filtered** list.

Comment: ya il do that and share the link, pls validate whether its correct or not

Comment: here i have added same form builder for edit as wel, please have a look at my demo code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192022/discussion-between-ivanes-and-bhrungarajni).